# How to change the page number from bottom center to top left?

Tags: formatting, header-footer, packages, format-files

[This .sty file](https://media.neurips.cc/Conferences/NeurIPS2020/Styles/neurips_2020.sty) is provided to me and the page number is currently at the bottom center (i.e. footer). I want to change it to the top left (i.e. header), which part is referring to the page number location? Or how can I narrow down my search and find out the corresponding region of the code? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Region of code you need are the `@oddhead` and `@oddfoot` macros.

This style seems not to redefine them, so they are "standard". If you require only page numbering in the header, you can use `\pagestyle{empty}` and define `@oddhead` with `\def` as

```
\makeatletter    
\def\@oddhead{\arabic{page}\hss}
\def\@oddfoot{}
...
\makeatother
```